# Is it true the following implication

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, logic

It is well known that $\forall x\in E, ( P(x) \vee Q(x)) \not\Rightarrow  ( \forall x\in E, P(x) )\vee  (\forall x\in E,Q(x))$.

Now if I suppose that $P(x)=P$ does not depend of $x$.

Have we $\forall x\in E, ( P \vee Q(x)) \Rightarrow  ( P )\vee  (\forall x\in E,Q(x))$.

Comment: Well, there are only two cases for $P$. Either it's true or it's false. Try plugging both in and see if the implication holds now.

Comment: Thnaks for your hint.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that implication holds. In fact, it is an equivalence. this is one of the Prenex laws: equivalences used to bring quantifiers in front of statements (if you go from right to left)

Here is an informal way to understand this equivalence

A universal $\forall x \ \phi (x)$ can be seen as a conjunction $\phi (a) \land \phi (b)\land \phi (c)...$ with $a,b,c,...$ denoting all the objects in the domain. As such:

$$ \forall x (P \lor Q(x)) = (P \lor Q(a)) \land (P \lor Q(b)) \land (P \lor Q(c))....=$$

$$P\lor (Q(a)\land Q(b) \land Q(c)...)= P \lor \forall x \ Q(x)$$

Comment: Thnaks a lot for your explanation.